# Modify XML to remove characters from result

Tags: xml

I have an xml that produces an attributed tag:

```
<Entity ITEMTYPE="PipeRun">
  <Attribute ItemTagFormat="(TagPrefix)-(OperFluidCode)-(NominalDiameter)-(TagSequenceNo)-(PipingMaterialsClass)-(InsulThick)(InsulationSpec)" FixedLength="()()()(4)()()()" FillingString="()()()(0)()()()" Alignment="(Right)(Right)(Right)()()()()" ProgID="()(ValidateNomDiam.ForeignCalc)()()(PipeSpec.CommodityCodeValidator)(SmartPlantInsulList.SPForeignCalc)(ProgramInsulList.SPForeignCalc)" /> 
  </Entity>
```

The (NominalDiameter) returns a value that has " for the format. ie, 2"

Is there a way to trim the returned value so the " will not display in the result. ie. 2

Comment: please update to include what language you are using to read the xml

Comment: I am looking at it in Notepad

Comment: _The (NominalDiameter) returns a value that has " for the format. ie, 2"_ What language are you using to read the attribute NominalDiameter from the XML file?